# What is the best plot for showing increase in medals won over the years in Olympics dataset

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am trying to learn pandas, plotly by playing with Olympics dataset from Kaggle. Plotly express's scatter with animation (from gapminder dataset) looks very impressive. I am trying to make a similar plot to show the trend in total, cumulative total number of medals won by different countries over the years in Olympics.

Here's how the dataframe looks like after running through some aggregation steps:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzqVM.png)

And here's what I tried:

```py
px.scatter(df3, x='Cum_Total', 
           y='Total', 
           animation_group='Country',
           animation_frame='Year',
           size='Cum_Total', size_max=100,
           color='Country', hover_name='Country',
           range_y=[1,300], range_x=[1,3000])
```

The animation doesn't seem to be a continuous one - it looks like discrete spots appearing and disappearing. I tried to sort the dataframe by "Year" and "Cum_Total" before plotting, but still not satisfied with the output. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: I saw that I had not written the sorted dataframe back to the original dataframe. In the plot, at the end of the animation the year value was 1912 ... 

Now I did
```python
df3 = df3.sort_values(['Year'])
```

Animation looks better than before, but still discrete flashes. May be due to USSR becoming RUS and ROC, etc. Still investigating

Answer (score 0):

- it's all about data prep - **pandas**
- dataframe needs to be uniform across years, countries and medals
- this actually aggregates summer and winter olympic medals

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, math
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import plotly.express as px

# download data set
sys.argv = [
    sys.argv[0]
] + "datasets download heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results".split(
    " "
)
kaggle.cli.main()

zfile = ZipFile("120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results.zip")
zfile.infolist()

# use CSV
df = pd.read_csv(zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[0]))
dfnoc = pd.read_csv(zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[1]))

idcols = [
    "Year",
    "Medal",
    "NOC",
]
# make data uniform.  i.e. every year has every country and every medal
dfp = (
    pd.merge(
        # calc medals for each year and country
        df.dropna(subset=["Medal"]).groupby(idcols).size().to_frame(),
        pd.DataFrame(
            index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                [df[c].dropna().unique() for c in idcols],
                names=idcols,
            )
        ),
        on=idcols,
        how="right",
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .sort_values(idcols)
    # calc cum sums across years
    .groupby(idcols[1:])
    .cumsum()
    .rename(columns={0: "Cum Count"})
    .reset_index()
    .merge(dfnoc, on="NOC")
)

# what countries are top performing... too many countries to fit on y-axis
topx = (
    dfp.loc[dfp["Year"].eq(dfp["Year"].max())]
    .groupby("NOC")
    .agg({"Cum Count": "sum"})
    .sort_values("Cum Count", ascending=False)
    .head(50)
)
# px.scatter(df2, x="Year", y="Team", size=0, color="Medal", animation_frame="Year")
fig = px.scatter(
    dfp.loc[dfp["NOC"].isin(topx.index)],
    x="region",
    y="Cum Count",
    log_y=True,
    size="Cum Count",
    size_max=100,
    color_discrete_sequence=["brown","gold","silver"],
    color="Medal",
    animation_frame="Year",
)
fig.update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "r": 0},
    yaxis={"range": [0, math.ceil(math.log10(dfp["Cum Count"].max()))]},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking all over plotly. Let me go through the details you presented and understand them thoroughly and reproduce it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Medal"].fillna("None",inplace=True)
df["Medal_Int"] = df["Medal"]
df["Medal_Int"].replace(["Gold","Silver","Bronze","None"],[1,2,3,4],inplace=True)
df_medals = df.groupby(["Year","Medal"]).count().reset_index()

df_entries = df.groupby(["Year"]).count().reset_index()
moving_avg = df_entries.rolling(window=5).mean()

cum_sum[:5]

sns.scatterplot(x="Year",y="ID",size="Medal",hue="Medal",data=df_medals[df_medals["Medal"] !="None"])
sns.lineplot(x="Year",y="ID",data=cum_sum)

sns.scatterplot(x="Year",y="ID",size="Medal",hue="Medal",data=df_medals[df_medals["Medal"] !="None"])
sns.lineplot(x="Year",y="ID",data=cum_sum)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).